# In Kotlin, why does variable?.isNotEmpty() show error? While variable!!.isNotEmpty() works fine

Tags: kotlin

I'm struggling with .isNotEmpty and  safe call operator, "?." in Kotlin. I've learned !!. is not recommended in Kotlin and ?. is the better one. But when I use .isNotEmpty, ?. makes an error and !!. run without error. Is there any reason why ?. causes error?

Here's the code on IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){

val unkownUser = "unkown User"
val name:String? = readLine()

println("Type the name\n")

if(name!!.isNotEmpty() && name.isNotBlank()) // name?.isNotEmpty()  doesn't work. wonder why
{
    println("$name")
}else{
    println(unkownUser)
}
```

Comment: Since it is nullable it is not known if name?.isNotEmpty() will evaluate to Boolean or null. In this case name?.isNotEmpty() will produce Boolean?.

This will work:
if(name != null && name.isNotEmpty() && name.isNotBlank())

Comment: `if (!name.isNullOrBlank()) { ... } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `name?.isNotEmpty()`:

1. If `name` is not null, it returns a `Boolean`
2. If it is null, it returns `null`

As a result, the return type is `Boolean?`, but `if()` wants a `Boolean`. That's why it doesn't work.

However, you can do: `if (name?.isNotEmpty() == true)`

Comment: Another variation is `if (name?.isNotEmpty() ?: true)`.  Or `if (!name.isNullOrEmpty())`.  (I don't know why the stdlib doesn't have a `isNotNullOrEmpty()` function…)

Answer (score 1):

As the IDE linting tool mention

```
Type mismatch.
Required:Boolean
Found:Boolean?
```

condition expect Boolean, not Boolean or Null so you can use

```
name?.let {}
```

or

```
!name.isNullOrBlank()
```

as mentioned in the comment above